# JzAzBz java implementation precision

Tags: java, colors

I made a java implementation of the new perceptualy uniform color space JzAzBz. OSA publication is : https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-25-13-15131&id=368272.

My java code is :

```
private double b = 1.15;
private double g = 0.66;
private double c1 = 3424 / Math.pow(2, 12);
private double c2 = 2413 / Math.pow(2, 7);
private double c3 = 2392 / Math.pow(2, 7);
private double n = 2610 / Math.pow(2, 14);
private double p = 1.7 * 2523 / Math.pow(2, 5);
private double d = -0.56;
private double d0 = 1.6295499532821566 * Math.pow(10, -11);

public void XYZToJab(double[] xyz, double[] jab) {
    double[] XYZp = new double[3];
    XYZp[0] = b * xyz[0] - ((b - 1) * xyz[2]);
    XYZp[1] = g * xyz[1] - ((g - 1) * xyz[0]);
    XYZp[2] = xyz[2];

    double[] LMS = new double[3];
    LMS[0] = 0.41478972 * XYZp[0] + 0.579999 * XYZp[1] + 0.0146480 * XYZp[2];
    LMS[1] = -0.2015100 * XYZp[0] + 1.120649 * XYZp[1] + 0.0531008 * XYZp[2];
    LMS[2] = -0.0166008 * XYZp[0] + 0.264800 * XYZp[1] + 0.6684799 * XYZp[2];

    double[] LMSp = new double[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LMSp[i] = Math.pow((c1 + c2 * Math.pow((LMS[i] / 10000.0), n)) / (1 + c3 * Math.pow((LMS[i] / 10000.0), n)), p);
    }

    double[] Iab = new double[3];
    Iab[0] = 0.5 * LMSp[0] + 0.5 * LMSp[1];
    Iab[1] = 3.524000 * LMSp[0] - 4.066708 * LMSp[1] + 0.542708 * LMSp[2];
    Iab[2] = 0.199076 * LMSp[0] + 1.096799 * LMSp[1] - 1.295875 * LMSp[2];

    jab[0] = (((1 + d) * Iab[0]) / (1 + d * Iab[0])) - d0;
    jab[1] = Iab[1];
    jab[2] = Iab[2];
}

public void JabToXYZ(double[] jab, double[] xyz) {

    double[] Iab = new double[3];
    Iab[0] = (jab[0] + d0) / (1 + d - d * (jab[0] + d0));
    Iab[1] = jab[1];
    Iab[2] = jab[2];

    double[] LMSp = new double[3];
    LMSp[0] = 1.0 * Iab[0] + 0.13860504 * Iab[1] + 0.05804732 * Iab[2];
    LMSp[1] = 1.0 * Iab[0] - 0.13860504 * Iab[1] - 0.05804732 * Iab[2];
    LMSp[2] = 1.0 * Iab[0] - 0.09601924 * Iab[1] - 0.81189190 * Iab[2];

    double[] LMS = new double[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LMS[i] = 10000 * Math.pow((c1 - Math.pow(LMSp[i], 1 / p)) / ((c3 * Math.pow(LMSp[i], 1 / p)) - c2), 1 / n);
    }

    double[] XYZp = new double[3];
    XYZp[0] = 1.92422644 * LMS[0] - 1.00479231 * LMS[1] + 0.03765140 * LMS[2];
    XYZp[1] = 0.35031676 * LMS[0] + 0.72648119 * LMS[1] - 0.06538442 * LMS[2];
    XYZp[2] = -0.09098281 * LMS[0] - 0.31272829 * LMS[1] + 1.52276656 * LMS[2];

    xyz[0] = (XYZp[0] + (b - 1) * XYZp[2]) / b;
    xyz[1] = (XYZp[1] + (g - 1) * XYZp[0]) / g;
    xyz[2] = XYZp[2];
}
```

When I test it running XYZToJab and then JabToXYZ I get a good precision for X and Z (delta order is E-9) but for Y I get a bad precision (delta order is 1-5%).

Is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: how is this related to javafx?

Comment: Where do your reference values come from?

Comment: OSA publication is : https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-25-13-15131&id=368272. I use values from 5.2 Full model of Jzazbz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is almost correct: The error lies in `JabToXYZ` where the prior to last line should be changed from

```
(XYZp[1] + (g - 1) * XYZp[0]) / g;
```

to

```
(XYZp[1] + (g - 1) * xyz[0]) / g;
```

However the fact that you are using rounded invert matrices to 6 decimal places in the `JabToXYZ` function will prevent you to get a clean inversion. You should try to compute the inverse at full double precision:

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{:0.15f}'.format})
>>> import colour.models.jzazbz
>>> colour.models.jzazbz.JZAZBZ_IZAZBZ_TO_LMS_P_MATRIX
array([[1.000000000000000, 0.138605043271539, 0.058047316156119],
       [1.000000000000000, -0.138605043271539, -0.058047316156119],
       [1.000000000000000, -0.096019242026319, -0.811891896056039]])
>>> colour.models.jzazbz.JZAZBZ_LMS_TO_XYZ_MATRIX
array([[1.924226435787607, -1.004792312595365, 0.037651404030618],
       [0.350316762094999, 0.726481193931655, -0.065384422948085],
       [-0.090982810982848, -0.312728290523074, 1.522766561305260]])
```

Comment: There is still a big delta difference : E-14 for X,Z and 1-4% for Y. Here are some values for X,Y,Z : 2.9531932455029164E-14     0.040567485325862185     1.8596235662471372E-15
-3.930189507173054E-14     0.039068586183160336     9.547918011776346E-15
2.55351295663786E-14     0.037373797245985774     -2.65898414397725E-14

Comment: Naive question but are you passing the numbers from one function to the other directly? E.g. JabToXYZ(XYZToJab(XYZ))

Comment: And is it possible to give the XYZ values and the values you get for both functions?

Comment: My code is :   
        double[] jab = new double[3];
        double[] rgb = new double[3];
        double[] xyz = new double[3];
        double[] xyz_ = new double[3];
        for (int r = 0; r < 256; r += 10) {
            for (int g = 0; g < 256; g += 10) {
                for (int b = 0; b < 256; b += 10) {
                    rgb[0] = r;
                    rgb[1] = g;
                    rgb[2] = b;
                    csc.RGBToXYZ(rgb, xyz);
                    csc.XYZToJab(xyz, jab);
                    csc.JabToXYZ(jab, xyz_);
                     }
}
        }
    }

Comment: and I substract System.out.println((xyz[0] - xyz_[0]) + "     " + (xyz[1] - xyz_[1]) + "     " + (xyz[2] - xyz_[2]));

Comment: Will answer to your email directly, very inconvenient on SO comments, will report back after.

Comment: Finally got it! xyz[1] = (XYZp[1] + (g - 1) * XYZp[0]) / g; should be (XYZp[1] + (g - 1) * xyz[0]) / g;